# Problem checking out navigation 1.8.3

Tags: ros, github, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was trying to checkout navigation 1.8.3 from github to my workspace. The commands I used are,

```
rosws set navigation --git https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation
/tree/navigation-1.8.3
rosws update
```

However, when doing update, I received the error:

```
[navigation] Fetching https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation
/tree/navigation-1.8.3 (version None) to /home/chengxiang/sim_workspace/navigation
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'git clone --recursive https://github.com
/ros-planning/navigation/tree/navigation-1.8.3 /home/chengxiang/sim_workspace
/navigation'
 errcode: 128:
fatal: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/navigation-1.8.3/info/refs 
not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
[/vcstools]
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'navigation' : [navigation]   
Checkout of https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/navigation-1.8.3 
version None into /home/chengxiang/sim_workspace/navigation failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'navigation' : [navigation] Checkout of   
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/navigation-1.8.3 version None 
into /home/chengxiang/sim_workspace/navigation failed.
```

I am not familar with github at all so I don't have a clue what's wrong.Could anyone please advise? I am using ROS-fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55981/problem-checking-out-navigation-1.8.3/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot clone a tag or branch from github using that url.

Instead, do:

```
rosws set navigation --git https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation --version-new navigation-1.8.3
rosws update navigation
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2013-02-22**:
Thanks KruseT. It works.